# SqlBulkCopy succeeds but inserts no records

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to insert a large number of records into a variety of tables. I cannot fit all of the records into memory at once, so instead, I am using an `IDataReader` implementation to fit some of the data into memory and then dump it into the database with `SqlBulkCopy`.

The problem I am experiencing is that the second time I try to write to a table, `SqlBulkCopy` will succeed but fail to actually insert the records. I thought it was a transaction issue at first, but I disabled all transactions on my connection and am still seeing the same problem. I can also independently confirm the size of the tables before and after both inside the code and outside.

Here is a code snippet:

```
long before = GetCount(tableName);
DataServerConnection conn = GetConnection();

using (var batch = conn.HasTransaction ?
    new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection)conn.IDbConnection, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default, (SqlTransaction)conn.Transaction) :
    new SqlBulkCopy((SqlConnection)conn.IDbConnection))
{
    batch.DestinationTableName = tableName;
    batch.WriteToServer(reader);
}

long after = GetCount(tableName);

if ((reader.Count + before) != after)
{
    throw new Exception($"Not all records inserted: Before = {before}, After = {after}, Reader Count = {reader.Count}, Expected = {reader.Count + before}");
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing? `GetCount(tableName)` is doing a simple

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [{tableName}]
```

`reader` is a basic `IDataReader` implementation that I have verified works other places on millions of records. `GetConnection()` is returning a wrapper for the connection which helps to prevent me from having to manage my connections constantly.

Comment: I wonder if its something simple. Try closing the SQLBulkCopy after each upload (if you aren't already doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your reader variable is declared so I'll tell you how I do it sometimes (and this doesn't mean it is the best way to do it).

First I declare a tableAdapter based on the dataSet I have:

```
DataSetTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter dataTable = new DataSetTableAdapter.MyTableAdapter();
```

Then, I create the connection.

```
SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(...);
```

And then the BulkCopy variable:

```
SqlBulkCopy insertData = new SqlBulkCopy(sql);
```

Once I have this, I start adding rows to the table Adapter like this:

```
dataTable.AddMyTableRow(...);
```

When I am finished, I do the bulk insertion:

```
sql.Open();
insertData.DestinationTableName = "MyTable";
insertData.WriteToServer(dataTable);
sql.Close();
```

Let me know if this helps you.